# Recursos compartidos (imagenes,documentos,etc..) en azure

Tags: azure

Alguien me puede indicar sobre que servicio de Azure se pueden publicar recursos compartidos (como digo, imágenes, documentos, etc..) para diferentes aplicaciones y como consumirlos

Answer (score 1):

Estimado,

Azure Storage es el servicio para almacenamiento el cual posee 4 tipos y el que mas se orienta para tu requerimiento es Azure Blob Storage:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs

En el enlace esta un ejemplo de como usar para C# las operaciones del servicio.
Buena suerte!

Comment: para que la respuesta tenga la calidad del sitio, del enlace extrae un ejemplo :)

Answer (score 0):

Con Azure lo puedes hacer con el servicio de [BLobs Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs)

Comment: para que la respuesta tenga la calidad del sitio, del enlace extrae un ejemplo :)